# hazelcast discovery service fails for serviceDns on kubernetes openshift origin

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, hazelcast, openshift-origin

I am deploying spring-boot application to the kubernetes openshift.
In this application I am using Hazelcast as a cache provider which I'm testing now. The Hazelcast should act as embedded cache manager and form p2p cloud with other pods. (no master).
As a discovery mechanism I am using `hazelcast-kubernetes` which is configured programatically this way:

```
@Bean
    public HazelcastInstance configHazelcastInstance(HazelcastProperties properties) {
        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(properties.getServiceDns()) || Strings.isNullOrEmpty(properties.getNamespace()))
            return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

        Config cfg = new Config();

        NetworkConfig networkConfig = cfg.getNetworkConfig();

        JoinConfig joinConfig = networkConfig.getJoin();

        joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(false);
        joinConfig.getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);
        joinConfig.getAzureConfig().setEnabled(false);
        joinConfig.getEurekaConfig().setEnabled(false);
        joinConfig.getGcpConfig().setEnabled(false);
        joinConfig.getKubernetesConfig().setEnabled(true);

        final HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategyFactory factory = new HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategyFactory();

        final DiscoveryStrategyConfig strategyConfig = new DiscoveryStrategyConfig(factory);
        strategyConfig.addProperty("service-dns", properties.getServiceDns());
        strategyConfig.addProperty("service-dns-timeout", "10");

        joinConfig.getDiscoveryConfig().addDiscoveryStrategyConfig(strategyConfig);

        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
    }
```

the message I'm getting on the application boot reads:

```
[main] WARN  c.h.s.d.integration.DiscoveryService - [10.129.2.253]:5701 [dev] [3.12.9] DNS lookup for serviceDns 'productizer.dev-product-configuration.svc.cluster.local' failed
```

when I do `nslookup ...` (can't copy terminal, sorry):
[image]

so it looks like serviceDns name exists, but hazelcast is unable to resolve it somehow.

can you recommend next steps, please?

EDIT:
with:

```
@Bean
    public HazelcastInstance configHazelcastInstance(HazelcastProperties properties) {
        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(properties.getServiceDns()) || Strings.isNullOrEmpty(properties.getNamespace()))
            return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

        Config cfg = new Config();

        NetworkConfig networkConfig = cfg.getNetworkConfig();

        JoinConfig joinConfig = networkConfig.getJoin();

        joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        joinConfig.getKubernetesConfig().setEnabled(true);
        joinConfig.getKubernetesConfig().setProperty("service-dns", properties.getServiceDns());
        joinConfig.getKubernetesConfig().setProperty("namespace", properties.getNamespace());
        joinConfig.getKubernetesConfig().setProperty("service-dns-timeout", "10");

        log.info(joinConfig.toString());

        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(cfg);
    }
```

I'm getting:

```
2020-10-22T15:31:13,767Z    [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.cached.thread-2] INFO  com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnector - [10.129.2.18]:5701 [dev] [3.12.9] Connecting to /10.128.2.214:5701, timeout: 10000, bind-any: true
2020-10-22T15:31:13,781Z    [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-in-0] INFO  c.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnection - [10.129.2.18]:5701 [dev] [3.12.9] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.129.2.18:58892 and /10.128.2.214:5701
2020-10-22T15:31:14,774Z    [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.priority-generic-operation.thread-0] ERROR com.hazelcast.cluster - [10.129.2.18]:5701 [dev] [3.12.9] Node could not join cluster. A Configuration mismatch was detected: Incompatible joiners! expected: , found: tcp-ip Node is going to shutdown now!
```

when booting up on openshift.

so I logged `joinConfig`:

```
c.f.p.c.HazelcastCacheConfiguration - JoinConfig{multicastConfig=MulticastConfig [enabled=false, multicastGroup=224.2.2.3, multicastPort=54327, multicastTimeToLive=32, multicastTimeoutSeconds=2, trustedInterfaces=[], loopbackModeEnabled=false], tcpIpConfig=TcpIpConfig [enabled=false, connectionTimeoutSeconds=5, members=[], requiredMember=null], awsConfig=AliasedDiscoveryConfig{tag='aws', enabled=false, usePublicIp=false, properties={}}, gcpConfig=AliasedDiscoveryConfig{tag='gcp', enabled=false, usePublicIp=false, properties={}}, azureConfig=AliasedDiscoveryConfig{tag='azure', enabled=false, usePublicIp=false, properties={}}, kubernetesConfig=AliasedDiscoveryConfig{tag='kubernetes', enabled=true, usePublicIp=false, properties={namespace=dev-product-configuration, service-dns-timeout=10, service-dns=productizer.dev-product-configuration.svc.cluster.local}}, eurekaConfig=AliasedDiscoveryConfig{tag='eureka', enabled=false, usePublicIp=false, properties={}}, discoveryConfig=DiscoveryConfig{discoveryStrategyConfigs=[], discoveryServiceProvider=null, nodeFilter=null, nodeFilterClass='null'}}
```

hazelcast: 3.12.9

hazelcast-kubernetes: 1.3.1

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64480946/hazelcast-discovery-service-fails-for-servicedns-on-kubernetes-openshift-origin

Comment: oh, really?! @RafałLeszko

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is not correct. It should be something like this:

```
        joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
        joinConfig.getKubernetesConfig().setEnabled(true);
        joinConfig.getKubernetesConfig().setProperty("service-dns", properties.getServiceDns());
        joinConfig.getKubernetesConfig().setProperty("service-dns-timeout", "10");
```

You don't need to create `HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategyFactory`.

Read more at:

- [Hazelcast Kubernetes Discovery documentation](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes)
- [Hazelcast Kubernetes Guide](https://guides.hazelcast.org/kubernetes-embedded/)

Comment: Can you add also you k8 configuration? Plus describe your service.

Comment: don't know what you mean by k8 conf. and service description shouldn't matter at this point. anyway, this morning it just started to work. so I'll delete the question probably